# Can't get very small divs to center

Tags: html, css

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nDWRm/4/

I want to make a plus and minus button using css or text or svg.

I tried this with the `css` and using textual `+` and `-` signs, but found those *never* line up. The problem is I can get it to look reasonably good on 100% zoom but when the zoom changes the `left` and `top` values also need to change to get the divs to center again. I haven't tried svg yet. I was just wondering why this doesn't seem possible.

**css**

```
#container{
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 0.1em solid black;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

.vert{
    top: 0.25em;
    left: 0.65em;
    position:absolute;
    width: 0.3em;
    height: 1.1em;
    background-color: #424A49;
    display: block;
}

.horz{
    top: 0.65em;
    left: 0.25em;
    position:absolute;
    width: 1.1em;
    height: 0.3em;
    background-color: #424A49;
    display: block;
}
```

**html**
​

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="vert"></div>
  <div class="horz"></div>
</div>​
```

Using a monotype font I made this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nDWRm/17/

if you change the font-size of `#container2` to for example `5em` you'll see it not render correctly. And on a aesthetic note the `+` sign has rounded corners and the `-` doesn't, which is not very pleasing :P.

this fiddle shows the problem with a font very clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/nDWRm/25/

Comment: Have you tried using a mono-type font on the + and -?

Comment: No hadn't thought about that. Will try now :)

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but adjusting your em values seems to have helped: http://jsfiddle.net/nDWRm/12/

Comment: @MichaelPeterson those aren't centered for me.

Comment: @the_ajp ahhh, sorry, must just be my browser

Comment: @MichaelPeterson you got a proper one then :P which is it? I'm using chrome 20.0 on win7.

Comment: i would not solve that with a font... They render differently on different OS/Browser configurations

Comment: strange, I'm using the same version of chrome on a mac. I'd have to agree with @meo

Comment: @meo that's why I originally asked the question with a solution with divs. :)

Comment: @the_ajp i am preparing my answer hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use random EM values. You have to calculate them on order to be translated to a round pixel value by the browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/meo/p7WMW/

(of course you can to it without scss, just by using http://pxtoem.com/ for example)

On js fiddle the base font size is 16px. So you need that in order to calculate your EM values.

**scss**

```
$base-font-size: 16px;

@function px2em($px, $contextPXSize : $base-font-size ){
    @return ( $px / $contextPXSize ) * 1em;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 2em;
    width: px2em(40px); height: px2em(40px);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    outline: 1px solid #000;
    &:after, &:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        background: black;
        left: 50%; top: 50%;   
    }
    &:after {
        height: px2em(30px); width: px2em(4px);
        margin: px2em(-15px) 0 0 px2em(-2px);        
    }
    &:before {
        height: px2em(4px); width: px2em(30px);
        margin: px2em(-2px) 0 0 px2em(-15px); 
    }
    &:hover:after {
        display: none;        
    }
}
```

what would result in:

**css**

```
a{
   position:relative;
   display:block;
   margin:2em;
   width:2.5em; height:2.5em;
   background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
   outline:1px solid #000
}
a:after,a:before{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   background:#000;
   left:50%; top:50%
}
a:after{
   height:1.875em;
   width:.25em;
   margin:-.938em 0 0 -.125em
}
a:before{
   height:.25em;
   width:1.875em;
   margin:-.125em 0 0 -.938em
}
a:hover:after{
   display:none
}
​
```

Comment: this sass stuff looks really cool. :) I will have a look at pxtoem.com too though I might have some problems introducing yet another tool into our dev team :).

Comment: How do you determine the base fontsize?

Comment: By inspecting some element that is unstyled and look at the computed font-size

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Monotype font like Courier and a display switch in jQuery to get the effect you're after. Also using line height and text-align: center; on the text to get this to work in mulitple zooms. The inner divs use 100% height and width so will always fill the container. No positions are needed, and you can increase the font size to make the symbols bigger :)

CSS:

```
#container{
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 0.1em solid black;
    cursor: pointer;    
    font-family: Courier;
}

.vert,
.horz{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #424A49;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

.vert
{
    display: none;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/nDWRm/13/

Comment: see updated question. the jquery is not part of the question though. I just want to center the `+` and `-` signs for several sizes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/nDWRm/21/ even at font size `5em` and zoomed way in the character stays in the center. As for the aesthetic quality of the font, you can find another monotype font that is more pleasing and include it with `@font-face`

Comment: Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/nDWRm/25/. I need the plus ans minus to be way bigger :P

Comment: But that example is not using the solution I gave you. You still have positioning on the inner divs. You're presenting me with the same issue you posted originally that I already solved. Go take a closer look :)

Comment: You're right. Using a font does still have some issues that's why I went for meo's solution.